# How can I execute following maven plugin before resolving the dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am from ANT background and newbie to Maven.

For some reason, I need to execute shell script before maven tries to fetch snapshot dependencies.
So I wrote following plugin configuration, but I not getting how can I make it invoke before resolving dependencies task.

I am using `Apache Maven 3.0.5`

Following is the part of my pom.xml

```
     <build>
        <finalName>edte</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>Docs/ci/delete_snapshots.sh</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>${user.home}</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I need to execute shell script before maven tries to fetch snapshot dependencies.* What do you mean? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: We have some projects, they are using Ant+Ivy to upload snapshots to our Nexus server. I faced some issues where we are not getting latest snapshots. So as a workaround, we want to delete those 2 snapshots from local repository.

Comment: Are you using `mvn -U ...`?

Comment: If you need to run something before Maven does something you simply have to run your scripte before you call Maven...otherwise the dependency solution will be done during the execution of Maven...